# Is there a way to extend SmartGit so it works with Gerrit?

Tags: java, version-control, gerrit, smartgit

We use SmartGit for much of our interaction with Git. SmartGit doesn't allow you to specify custom URIs for remote branches. It likes you to select from a list, which doesn't include changes listed under refs/for/master. I was wondering if there was some way to add a custom menu action to SmartGit for checking out from Gerrit. I guess there's no way to add macros in SmartGit? I understand I can always use commandline or eGit, but I'm trying to keep all git management under one tool, if at all possible.

### Update

Forgot to mention, I'm interested in getting checkouts to work as well. For specific refs which represent changes. For example:  refs/changes/10/35020/1.

Comment: So you are interested to enter an arbitrary ref in the Clone wizard?

Answer (score 2):

In SmartGit you can use **Push Advanced**, select **Into a non-default remote branch** there and enter `refs/for/master`. SmartGit currently does not allow to pull an arbitrary ref nor does it display any other refs than `refs/heads`, `refs/remotes` and `refs/tags`.